# Saving blob with JavaScript always saves an empty file

Tags: javascript, firefox, blob, filesaver.js

The most intriguing part of the following code is that it works perfectly when the server is run as localhost, but it doesn't when the server is on a remote computer. The received blob size is accurate but saving blob to a file with FileSaver.saveAs produces an empty file. Can't figure out where the problem is?

```
function downloadResultsZip(id, reqDelay) {
let uri = `https://etc...`;
let delay = 0;
let timerId = setTimeout(function request() {
    fetch(uri).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 202) { // Request accepted.
            delay = reqDelay;
            timerId = setTimeout(request, delay);
        } else if (response.status === 200) { // OK
            let zipFileName = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition').match(/.*"(.*)".*/)[1];
            //
            response.blob().then(function (zipBlob) {
                clearTimeout(timerId);
                //alert("zipBlob size = " + zipBlob.size); // ok, accurate
                FileSaver.saveAs(zipBlob, zipFileName); // Problem!
            });
        } else {
            if (response.status === 400) { // Bad Request
                alert('Server responded with an error: \"input parameters are not valid\".');
            } else {
                alert('Error! Server calculation has failed.');
            }
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        }
    });
}, delay);
```

}

1st EDIT.

I've just found out that the source code is correct but doesn't work as expected only in Firefox 71. In Chrome 79 and Edge 44 (EdgeHTML 18) works without issues. Since I'm quite new to JS I'm wondering how to overcame this issue. I've also tried the basic approach with creating  tag and href attribute pointing to URI service and then clicking on that link, but I succeeded to save only approx 1 KB of data, not 5.3 MB as was expected.

Comment: Is the document the same origin as the URI?

Comment: Yes, they are. Note that `alert("zipBlob size = " + zipBlob.size)` returns `zipBlob size = 5556200` no matter whether the server is localhost or is on another address. But, in the second case, `FileSaver.saveAs` creates a file with accurate file name but of length 0. On localhost it saves a file of a size of 5.3 MB and that's OK.

Comment: I edited original post with the issue resolution.